# error: request for member ‘GetSum’ in test’, which is of pointer type ‘Test*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am learning how to make an array with Class. I used malloc to make a ptr array with the name test. But when I want to use the function of the value in the array, I got an error :
error: request for member ‘GetSum’ in
test’, which is of pointer type ‘Test*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:  
    Test(int x, int y)
        {
                this->x = x;
                this->y = y;
        }

        int GetSum()
        {
                return ans;
        }

private:
        int x;
        int y;
        int ans;
};

int main()
{
        Test *test = (Test*)malloc(sizeof(Test) * 5);

        *(test + 0) = Test(1, 2);
        int sum = *(test + 0).GetSum(); /* ERROR HERE */

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look for [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: Unrelated, but don't do `malloc` plus manual initialization. That is what `new` is for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list, pick learning resources from there, many of them are online. The reason I'm saying that is that your code looks like you're learning from a bad teacher. In any case, that expression isn't evaluated in the order you think, so adding extra parens should help: `(*(test + 0)).GetSum()`. This will not make it good C++ code though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **problem** is that `operator.` has higher precedence than `operator*` due to rules of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). This means that the expression `*(test + 0).GetSum()` is ***grouped as***(or equivalent to) writing:

```
//this is equivalent to what your wrote
*( (test + 0).GetSum() )
```

---

##### Solution

To **solve** this error you can explicitly use the parenthesis around `*(test + 0)` to override this precedence as shown below:

```
//--------v-----------v-------------> works now 
int sum = (*(test + 0)).GetSum();
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3h46rhM5G)

---

Also I would recommend using `new` instead of `malloc` when working in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, this is not C++!
@Jason already showed, how to solve the given error message.

To make it C++ (and not C)

1. use [array `new[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new)

   ```
   Test *test = new Test[5];
   ```

   or better yet an [`array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

   ```
   std::array<Test, 5> test;
   ```

   if it must be dynamically, use [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

   ```
   std::vector<Test> test;
   ```
2. access the array elements by [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access), e.g.

   ```
   int sum = test[0].GetSum();
   ```

   This avoids the calculation and [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) problems.